# Scala: Reuse parameter name in extended classe

Tags: scala

In this code, the parameter `a` in `B` is different from the `A.a`

```
class A(var a:String)

class B(a:String) extends A(a) {
    println(a) // Use B.a

  def p() {
   println(a)
 }
}

val b=new B("abc")
b.p() // "abc"
b.a="def"
b.p() // "abc" and not "def"
```

I can rename the parameter in B like this :

```
class B(_a:String) extends A(_a) {
    println(_a) // Use B.a

  def p() {
   println(a)
 }
}
```

but I would like to maintain the name 'a', for the Scaladoc, and compatibility with the syntax `B(a="def")`.
How I can resolve this scenario ?

Comment: Would it be feasible to resort to composition, rather then inheritance?

Comment: Making the class immutable would resolve the problem. It would force you to `val res = b.copy(a = "def")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the primary constructor private and add a secondary constructor which has `a` as the name:

```
class B private (_a:String, ignore: Unit) extends A(_a) {
    def this(a) { this(a, ()) }

    println(_a) // Use B.a

    def p() {
      println(a)
    }
}
```

But this seems like it could easily lead to confusion. So I'd look for alternative designs, as the comments to the question suggest.

Comment: The code must be
class B private (_a:String, ignore: Unit) extends A(_a) {
    def this(a:String) { this(a, ()) }

    println(_a) // Use B.a

  def p() {
   println(a)
  }
}

Comment: Fixed, I was in a bit of a hurry.